# 4 activities, check which activity sent me to the final activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Basically I have 4 screens, 4 activities. Data is entered on activity one, depending if data matches what i need, Activity 1 send me to activity two from a button. If it doesn't match, sends me to activity 3. Both 2 and 3 activities take me to Activity 4 after data is entered on those screens. Then the data is used in Activity 4. But I only need the data from one of them depending where it was entered.

How can I check in Activity 4, which Activity was started either 2, or 3.

Thanks

Comment: if you have to send too much data from an activity to others, I think fragment will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send an intent with the intent to start the activity 4 from activity 2 and 3 like this

```
Intent inetent=new Intent(2nd_activity.this,4th_activity.class);
intent.putExtra("activity_name","second");
startActivity(intent);
```

similary for 3rd activity with activity_name value third and in your 4th activity you can retrieve this value to know from which activity it has been started

```
String activityName=getIntent().getIntentExtra("activity_name");
```

Comment: hmm this would indeed work. But what if I add other activities in between. So now there's activities 2 & 3 they send to 4 for more data which goes to activity 5 which is the final one. so now activity 5 needs that intent.

Comment: pass the value from 4th activity to 5th as you wish what is the problem here?

Comment: I would if I could, but I don't have enough reputation. when I get enough reputation I will. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**in all from Activity (A,B and C):**

add the below line while starting intent. 
    intent.putExtra("TAG","ActivityName");

**In Final Activity(Activity D - Final Activity):**

String tag = getIntent().getExtra("TAG");

at last compare tag and decide.

Comment: check my updated question in the comments of Pramod Yadavs answer. Would SharedPrefs do the job here as well?

Comment: There is really no need of shared preference in this case. This is run time data and and you you want to maintain a flag to track the activity. once the target activity is opened, then there is no scope for the same. Shared preference is used only when you need the value to be persisted through entire execution of the app as well as in future. Hope you are clear.